# How to make a thread wait for other threads to finish

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a program where I created two threads. In one thread I assigned a value to integers `a` and `b`. In the second thread, I want to access `a` and `b`, to change their values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct data {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct data temp;

void *assign(void *temp)
{
    struct data *new;

    new = (struct data *) temp;
    new->a = 2;
    new->b = 2;
    printf("You are now in thread1..\n The value of a and b is: %d, %d", new->a + 1, new->b + 1);
    printf("\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *add(void *temp1)
{
    struct data *new1;
    new1 = (struct data *) temp1;
    printf("You are now in thread 2\nValue of a and b is: %d, %d\n", new1->a - 1, new1->b - 1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[2];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void *status;
    int rc, t;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, assign, (void *) &temp);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, add, (void *) &temp);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    for (t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[t], &status);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("Main: completed join with thread %ld having a status of %ld\n", t, (long) status);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

But the above program executes the two threads simultaneously. Sometimes I get

```
thread1..
The value of a and b is: 3, 3
thread 2
Value of a and b is: 1, 1
```

and sometimes I get

```
thread 2
Value of a and b is: -1, -1
You are now in thread1..
The value of a and b is: 3, 3
```

I want to make thread-2(add) to wait for thread-1(assign) to finish and exit. How can I implement it?

Comment: See [pthread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).

Comment: No point in initializing, configuring, and destroying `attr` if you're not going to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If one thread must wait for the other to finish, I see three options:

1. Make the second thread do `pthread_join()` on the first one.
2. Use a condition variable to signal the second thread when the first one is done.
3. Stop using threads, as it's pointless to have one whose only job is to wait for another one.  Just put the logic sequentially in a single thread.

Comment: 3. is the best answer. :-)

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: it'd be my pick for sure, in the absence of other information.

Comment: i suppose i should go for 1 or 2... well, i'm just trying to know more about threading, and in case this situation occurs.. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - it's important to remember that many of the code samples people post as their question are academic exercises meant to strip away all of the excess fodder around what is the core of their question, or they're doing it because they are attempting to experiment with something that they have little experience with. Telling people their question is wrong is often the wrong answer.

Comment: @antiduh : indeed., i am a noob and trying to learn about threading.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a semaphore.

1. Define a global semaphore with value 1.
2. Before creating two threads, you do a P operation, and the value of the semaphore will be 0.
3. In thread 1 after you have assigned the value of a and b, you do a V operation. The value of semaphore will be 1.
4. In thread 2 before you do the print, add an operation V. If thread 1 hasn't finished the assignment, thread 2 will go to sleep until thread 1 have finished.

That's my opinion about this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple threads, I mean more than two threads you have to pthread_join on every other thread and is not efficient solution. In my opition you should used pthrea_mutex_lock(&lock) and pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock) just after entering and exiting from the thread function. For an instance:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void *assign(void *temp)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)
    struct data *new;

    new = (struct data *) temp;
    new->a = 2;
    new->b = 2;
    printf("You are now in thread1..\n The value of a and b is: %d, %d", new->a + 1, new->b + 1);
    printf("\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *add(void *temp1)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)
    struct data *new1;
    new1 = (struct data *) temp1;
    printf("You are now in thread 2\nValue of a and b is: %d, %d\n", new1->a - 1, new1->b - 1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```